# Why can't I build my xamarin PCL project?

Tags: xamarin, build, uwp, nuget

First of all, sorry for my bad English. I'm developing a Xamarin PCL application for Android and UWP. 
For android everything works but for UWP it doesn't. When I build in debug mode it also works fine but that is because the common language runtime exceptions are off. The errors occur when it hits `Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(e);`

These are the errors:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException occurred
>   HResult=0x80070002
>   Message=Could not load file or assembly 'clrcompression, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Het systeem kan het opgegeven bestand niet vinden.
>   Source=
>   StackTrace:
>   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
>   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
>
> System.IO.FileNotFoundException occurred
>   HResult=0x80070002
>   Message=Could not load file or assembly 'clrjit, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Het systeem kan het opgegeven bestand niet vinden.
>   Source=
>   StackTrace:
>   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
>   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
>
> System.IO.FileNotFoundException occurred
>   HResult=0x80070002
>   Message=Could not load file or assembly 'sqlite3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Het systeem kan het opgegeven bestand niet vinden.
>   Source=
>   StackTrace:
>   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
>   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
>
> System.IO.FileNotFoundException occurred
>   HResult=0x80070002
>   Message=Could not load file or assembly 'ucrtbased, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Het systeem kan het opgegeven bestand niet vinden.
>   Source=
>   StackTrace:
>   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
>   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)

The app contains multiple nuget packages and multiple portable library classes.
App PCL:

```
package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="10.0.3" targetFramework="portable45-
net45+win8" /
package id="Rg.Plugins.Popup" version="1.0.4" targetFramework="portable45-
net45+win8" /
package id="SQLite.Net.Core-PCL" version="3.1.1" 
targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8" /
package id="SQLite.Net-PCL" version="3.1.1" targetFramework="portable45-
net45+win8" /
package id="System.Runtime" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="portable45-
net45+win8" /
package id="System.Threading" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="portable45-
net45+win8" /
package id="Xam.Plugins.DownloadManager" version="1.3.2" 
targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8" /
package id="Xamarin.Forms" version="2.4.0.18342" 
targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8" /
package id="ZXing.Net.Mobile" version="2.2.9" targetFramework="portable45-
net45+win8" /
package id="ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms" version="2.2.9" 
targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8" /
```

UWP:

```
"Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform": "6.0.1",
"Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications": "2.0.0",
"Newtonsoft.Json": "10.0.3",
"Rg.Plugins.Popup": "1.0.4",
"SQLite.Net-PCL": "3.1.1",
"SQLite.Net.Core-PCL": "3.1.1",
"System.IO": "4.3.0",
"System.Net.Sockets": "4.3.0",
"System.ObjectModel": "4.3.0",
"System.Runtime": "4.3.0",
"System.Runtime.Handles": "4.3.0",
"System.Threading": "4.3.0",
"Xam.Plugin.Connectivity": "3.0.3",
"Xam.Plugins.DownloadManager": "1.3.2",
"Xamarin.Forms": "2.4.0.18342",
"ZXing.Net.Mobile": "2.2.9",
"ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms": "2.2.9"
```

**Library classes 1:**

PCL:

```
package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="10.0.3" targetFramework="portable45-
net45+win8" /
package id="SQLite.Net.Core-PCL" version="3.1.1" 
targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8" /
package id="SQLite.Net-PCL" version="3.1.1" targetFramework="portable45-
net45+win8" /
package id="Xamarin.Forms" version="2.4.0.18342" 
targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8" /
```

UWP:

```
Microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform
newtonsoft.json
sqlite.net-pcl
sqlite.net.core-pcl
xamarin.froms
```

**Library classes 2:**

PCL:

```
package id="Xamarin.Forms" version="2.4.0.18342" 
targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8" /
```

UWP:

```
microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform
microsoft.toolkit.uwp.notifications.
sqlite for universal windows platform
universal windows
windows desktop extensions for the uwp
windows IoT extensions for the UWP
Windows Mobile extensions for the uwp
Windows Team extensions for the uwp
xam.plugin.connectivity
xamarin.forms
```

Does anybody know how to fix this problem?

UPDATE:
Error 1 (clrcompression) is fixed.
This was because the base project uses an package that has an dependency of System.io.compression of version 4.1.0 and the app used 4.3.0 
(but nuget packages  was the same version) after I changed that it was fixed. But this can't easily be found. That's why the other 3 errors remain.

Comment: Maybe this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33743493/why-visual-studio-2015-cant-run-exe-file-ucrtbased-dll

Comment: Sadly it doesn't.

Comment: I have downloaded almost everything in visual studio. I have coppied the dll's to the debugfolders but the issue still remains.

Comment: as far as I remember, latest version of clrcompression that comes with the Xamarin is not fully comptible with the latest version of Xamarin. I faces the same issue a few months ago and what I did was installing clrcompression library's earlier versions from nuget manually.

Comment: When i'm installing a nuget package "system.io.chompression.clrcompression-x86" it the error is that the clrcompression.dll is dubble used. this is the package microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform