# Targeting the Windows 7 OS with Visual Studio 2017 gives a ucrtbased.dll missing error

Tags: c++, .net, visual-studio-2017

I have a client that is running a Windows 7 machine and I want to him build an .exe that he can run on his computer. However, since I am running Windows 10, I am building everything in Visual Studio 2017. The program I am making is a Winforms CLR C++ program. I put in the Windows 7 WINVER define in one of the C++ files:

```
#define WINVER 0x0601
```

The compile the project with the following properties:
[image: VSProjConfig]

I send him an .exe file but when he opens it up, it gives him a an error saying that he is **missing the ucrtbased.dll**. I verified that he has the correct .NET framework installed on his computer:

[image: netFramework]

What could be the cause of this?

Comment: The runtime DLL(s) with filename(s) ending in `d` are usually the debug versions.  Did you give your client a debug build?  If so these DLL(s) cannot be re-distributed; you should give your client a release build.

Comment: Does the client have the Visual C++ 2017 redistributables installed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why Visual Studio 2015 can't run exe file (ucrtbased.dll)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33743493/why-visual-studio-2015-cant-run-exe-file-ucrtbased-dll)

Comment: Actually you are right, I did send him a debug build, I'll try sending him a release build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build and send him a release copy. He will still need the appropriate windows libraries.

ucrtbase (Universal C Runtime) is the replacement for the msvc* runtime dlls.

To get the correct runtime, see https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48234
and also possibly https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2999226/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows
if you have problems.

Comment: It's a debug DLL and cannot be redistributed.

Comment: That's not the only problem. I have updated my answer.

Comment: There aren't any options to add have a target older than 8.1. https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyXOy.png I think I also saw somewhere that targeting 8.1 would also work on Windows 7?

Comment: When I do the 'repair' option on VS2017 installer, it gives me the following options:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/unBQG.png

Comment: Hmm, upon hammering at google for a bit [I have determined](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/ide/general-property-page-project) that the Windows 8.1 SDK is also the target for Windows 7 development. I was mistaken on that account. I will correct my answer.
So... just get him the release version and the runtime and you should be set.